# Angular + Firebase error "Spread types may only be created from object types."

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Good day,

I'm stuck with angular+firabase since I am new with this not sure which part I am missing, maybe a version issue or misdeclaration. Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Here's my ts code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFireDatabase} from '@angular/fire/database';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CategorieService {

  constructor(private db:AngularFireDatabase) {}
  getAllCategories()
  {
    return this.db.list('categories')
                  .snapshotChanges()
                  .pipe(
                    map(change=>change.map(c=>({
                      key:c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val()
                    })))
                  )
  }

}
```

and the error is

```
Spread types may only be created from object types. ts(2698)
```

Comment: A very similar question was posted here about 12 hours ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61303841/why-am-i-getting-an-error-stating-that-spread-types-may-only-be-created-from-o. Unfortunately without an answer so far, but I'm linking to it just in case it gets answer there.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sure no problem :)

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
...c.payload.exportVal()
```